# Writing a table constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp, check-constraints

I have three tables as :

Student (snum(primary key),sname)

Enrolled (snum,tname)

Training (tname(primary key),tdate,thour,troom)

I have to put a constraint to the table Enrolled so that a student can not register courses(tname) that given at the same time.

I have tried something like this but I think it just gives the lessons with unique times:

```
select tname from Training T1 where tdate not in (select tdate from Training T2 where T1.tdate=T2.tdate)
```

Comment: Not clear what you want the query to return. Do you just want it to omit courses in `Training` that have the same hours as courses in `Enrolled`, and return all the others?

Comment: I want to make a constraint to the enrolled table so that when a student picks multiple courses he or she doesn't pick the lessons which are given at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create such a constraint if you agree to have some redundancy.

This is what you do:

1. Create a unique constraint on `(tname, tdate, thour)` in `Training`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Training ADD CONSTRAINT
     UQ_Training_NameDateHour UNIQUE (tname, tdate, thour);
   ```
2. Add two more columns to `Enrolled`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Enrolled ADD tdate date NOT NULL;
   ALTER TABLE Enrolled ADD thour int NOT NULL;
   ```

   I am guessing the types here. They need to match the types of the corresponding columns in `Training`.
3. Have the new columns be part of a reference to `Training`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Enrolled ADD CONSTRAINT
     FK_Enrolled_Training FOREIGN KEY (tname, tdate, thour)
                  REFERENCES Training (tname, tdate, thour);
   ```

   And if you already have a reference that points to `tname` alone, you can remove it.
4. Finally, create a unique constraint in `Enrolled` to ensure that `tdate` and `thour` are unique per `snum`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Enrolled ADD CONSTRAINT
     UQ_Enrolled_NumDateHour UNIQUE (snum, tdate, thour);
   ```

This way you will have a formal constraint on the `Enrolled` table that will ensure a student cannot have trainings that start at the same time.

Naturally, when you insert rows into `Enrolled`, the references must consist of all three components. If that seems to you too big a price, then you will probably have to resort to using triggers, [as suggested by Norbert van Nobelen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29055470/297408).

Comment: Thanks but I guess if I add a unique constraint on Training table then I wont have lessons which will start at the same time.I want lessons which start at the same time I just don't want the students to take them when they are enrolling

Comment: No, the unique constraint in Training will still allow you to have trainings that start at the same hour. `tname` is already unique because it's a PK. Including `tname` into another unique key doesn't introduce any more restriction. That unique key is needed only for you to be able to reference the three columns (to make sure there is no discrepancy in date and hour between the two tables).

Comment: You probably overlooked the fact that the constraint is not just on date and hour but on name, date and hour. So you can have entries like `Databases, 2015-03-30, 10` and `Java, 2015-03-30, 10` - they are distinct and will not violate the unique constraint.

Comment: Yes now I got it, you are right,thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to write a trigger on "before insert" and "before update".
In the trigger get the data you want to compare and then refuse to insert or update when the data does not match your criteria

Comment: I want to learn how to construct that data with the given values in the tables.